# s3cmd put command: Upload: Command not found

Tags: bash, amazon-s3

So I want to `put` a file onto s3. Here is the cmd:

```
/usr/bin/s3cmd --rr --access_key="$access_key" --secret_key="$secret_key" put "$FILEPATH/$ZIPPED_FILE" "$s3_path/$ZIPPED_FILE"
```

And this works perfectly except in my bash shell, it prints out this message: `upload:: command not found`. Anyone encounter this?

Comment: Not sure this is a software development question, unless you're trying to modify or fix the source to `s3cmd`.

Comment: That said -- after looking at the source to `s3cmd`, I think I know what's going on here. However, it has to do with the context in which you're making this call -- the code given in the question isn't sufficient to reproduce it. Please ensure that you're providing a [mcve]: The shortest possible code that **actually produces your problem**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This almost certainly means you're running the stdout of `s3cmd` as a command itself. For instance, that could happen if you were to run:

```
# BAD: runs the command, then runs its output as another command
`/usr/bin/s3cmd --rr --access_key="$access_key" --secret_key="$secret_key" put "$FILEPATH/$ZIPPED_FILE" "$s3_path/$ZIPPED_FILE"`
```

To fix that, just take the backticks out, and write:

```
# GOOD: just invokes your command, with its output written to stdout
/usr/bin/s3cmd --rr --access_key="$access_key" --secret_key="$secret_key" put "$FILEPATH/$ZIPPED_FILE" "$s3_path/$ZIPPED_FILE"
```